Making a 110/220 dryer work without a 220V outlet
I was given a Maytag dryer that was used in a house at 220v. A plaque inside reads 110/220. I replaced the wire but this only makes the light inside to work.
I live in city housing, which means they will not let me run a 220 outlet.
I do have basic electrical tech knowledge from HS & college.
Right in the room is a dedicated outlet for 110v 30Amps and in the next room is the same, each on separate fuses and line. Observing polarities could I combine them, or am I right in thinking this will only explode?
Can I make this work somehow? Once I asked an expert and he was the only one who vaguely explained the Maytag what Maytag meant by 110/220 as putting 2 leads(I assume (+) and 2 leads (-)) to L1 & L2 . This was where I got the idea but with it being 2 AC outlets, in the same apartment, I think they can still be out of phase?

Being city/you do not own, you can only plug/unplug stuff in.  You should not even think of touching wires.  Best is to try to trade your dryer for an apartment type dryer that runs on 110/120v.  220/240 volt dryers uses 120v for the motor and 240v for the heat element.

A little outdated unused vaguely recalled electrical knowledge and a lack of common sense can get you in big trouble. Find some common sense and a dryer that's actually made to operate on 120V. Or hang clothes on hangers to dry.

Removed the "fresh meat" distraction, reformatted slightly for readability.

@jsotola it means he's a n00b to SE.

@jsotola, and all I offended sorry for fresh meat reference I meant no disrespect with calling myself "Fresh Meat" It was my attempt at bad humor.  It is insulting but directed at myself for my total lack of knowledge in this field that I studied but have since forgotten. And am quite gullible

@RobertT no offense taken

The big power user is the heater; the control timer and the motor may be 110V. If so, it may be possible to set this up to run on 110 (120) volts, at the cost of longer during times -- and drying on low heat is often recommended to save power anyway. So check the manufacturer's installation instructions to see if they document a real 110V configuration.
If they don't, find a buyer for this unit and get yourself one that can be configured for 110V only. There is no good way to get 220V from two 110V outlets, and I can't recommend even attempting the bad ways.
You could try asking your landlord if they'd be willing to hire an electrician to put in a 220V outlet, if you cover the cost...
Don't forget that a dryer needs to be able to exhaust to outside, unless you want to deal with high humidity in the living space... and even if the latter is acceptable you want to filter the output so you aren't breathing fabric dust. (I have a friend who got by with using stockings to filter the exhaust air for many years...)

First -- do you have a dryer VENT?  I.E. a 4-6" tube routed from the laundry room to outside?  Because if you don't, then a cheapie / "fell off a truck" dryer simply isn't going to work in your locale.  I've lived in an apartment where that was done. It really does not work, I know you think "surely it must be better than a clothesline" nope.
You don't actually have multiple 30A circuits in your apartment, there's no such thing, no one puts 120V/30A circuits in apartments.  The only residential use for one is small travel trailers towed behind a truck, as in small RVs.  So no, you're either wishful thinking, or someone in the past over-fused the circuits. Real common for tenants to try to stop fuse blows by over-fusing the circuit, you find all 30A fuses in there even though the house wiring is 15-20A.  You cannot hang a dryer on that.
So yeah, this is not gonna happen. I suppose you could rewire it so the heating element is on 120V, but that still doesn't sove the humidity problem.
Sorry. You simply do not have enough electricity to -- OH WAIT. THIS JUST IN.
Yes. You'll need to save up your nickels, but yes - they now make dryers which work fine on normal household circuits, and importantly, do not require a dryer vent.  They also save a lot of electricity.  Some of them have a condensate pump to shove water down the washing machine drain, but I bet you don't have a proper laundry area with one of those, so other models have a condensate bucket you must empty every couple of loads.
